# Flutter: How can I set initial value to a textController and change it after?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stepper and some TextFormFields with controller in the first step. I want to show in the TextField an initialValue and if I change the value want to set the new value to the controller and keep it on change step.
Now, I can change the value of the controller but not keep it on change step

**Edit Page**

```dart
class EditProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uid;

  const EditProfilePage({Key? key, required this.uid}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditProfilePageState createState() => _EditProfilePageState();
}

class _EditProfilePageState extends State<EditProfilePage> {
  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();

 int _index = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _nameController.addListener(() {
      final String text = _nameController.text;
      _nameController.value = _nameController.value.copyWith(
        text: text,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _nameController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
;
final UserProvider userProvider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);

_nameController.text = userProvider.getUser.name;
return Scaffold(
    ...
    body: Stepper(
        controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, ControlsDetails details) {
          if (_index == 2) {
            return Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      userProvider.updateName(
                          _nameController.text, userProvider.getUser.uid);
                    },
                    child: const Text('SAVE'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Row();
          }
        },
        currentStep: _index,
        onStepCancel: () {
          _index > 0 ? setState(() => _index -= 1) : null;
        },
        onStepContinue: () {
          _index < 2 ? setState(() => _index += 1) : null;
        },
        onStepTapped: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _index = index;
          });
        },
        steps: <Step>[
          Step(
            title: const Text('Personal Info'),
            content: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Column(children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: _nameController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Name',
                      labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                      border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: Divider.createBorderSide(context),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: Divider.createBorderSide(context),
                      ),
                      filled: true,
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 24,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UserProvider**

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  User? _user;
  final AuthMethods _authMethods = AuthMethods();

  User get getUser => _user!;

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    User user = await _authMethods.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }


  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```dart
TextEditingController.fromValue(TextEditingValue(text: "initial value"));
```

or

```dart
TextEditingController(text: "initial value")
```

**Update**

using nullable `TextEditingController` and getting context using `WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback` inside `initState` to read provider.

```dart
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  String userName = "intial UserName";
  Future<void> setUser(String name) async {
    userName = name;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class EditProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uid;

  const EditProfilePage({Key? key, required this.uid}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditProfilePageState createState() => _EditProfilePageState();
}

class _EditProfilePageState extends State<EditProfilePage> {
  TextEditingController? _nameController;

  int _index = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); // to have context
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      final provider = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false);

      debugPrint("Got Name : ${provider.userName}");
      _nameController = TextEditingController(text: provider.userName);
      _nameController?.addListener(() {
        final text = _nameController == null ? "" : _nameController!.text;
        provider.setUser(text);
      });
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _nameController?.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Consumer<UserProvider>(
            builder: (context, value, child) {
              return Text(value.userName);
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _nameController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Name',
              labelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
              border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: Divider.createBorderSide(context),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: Divider.createBorderSide(context),
              ),
              filled: true,
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 24,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

More about [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html).

Comment: I use that (_nameController.text = userProvider.getUser.name;) but when I change the name and then change step the name resets to his initail value

Comment: You like to get initial value from provider ?

Comment: Yes, I would like that. this Is my first proyect and Im not quite confident about what I should do

Comment: Please be specific while asking question, you can edit the question to specify the issue and the desire result you like to have.

Comment: For now, you can comment the provider snippet and  save value inside `TextButton`.  Hope current approach will work

Comment: I want to keep the new value of _nameController (which will have an initial value from provider)when I change it through all the steps

Comment: Can you include your `UserProvider`?

Comment: I ve just included

Comment: Check update answer

Answer (score 1):

To set the initial value to a `TextEditingController`

```
 final _nameController = TextEditingController(text: 'initial value');
```

And to update the value:

```
 _nameController.text='new value';
```

Comment: I use that (_nameController.text = userProvider.getUser.name;) but when I change the name and then change step the name resets to his initail value